# Using Linux C. I use sleep in thread function,but the whole process ends?

Tags: multithreading, posix

when the program goes to sleep`sleep (1)`in a thread function ,it suddenly ends. Does it have something to do with thread?

```
void send_packet(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in dest_addr)
{   
int packetsize;
while( nsend < MAX_NO_PACKETS)
{      
    printf("send %d\n", nsend);
    nsend++;
    packetsize=pack(nsend); 
    if( sendto(sockfd,sendpacket,packetsize,0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr,sizeof(dest_addr) )<0  )
    {       
        perror("sendto error");
        continue;
    }
    printf(" %d\n", packetsize);
    sleep(1); 
}
}
```

---

```
int find_host(void * arg)
{

send_packet(sockfd, present_addr);
recv_packet(sockfd, recvpacket, from);
```

---

```
pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, find_host, (void *)&inaddr);
```

Comment: show some code, we can't know what you do. Basically you could suppose that your sleep is probably interrupted by a signal.

Comment: Is the main thread still running or does it exit while the sender thread is executing?

Comment: You should get rid of the Sleep(1), and it's polling loop, entierely and use sensiblwe inter-thread comms, (condvar or semaphore), to signal the thread to start sending stuff.   Code like this gives Sleep() a bad name:)

Comment: @Werner Henze it ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one comment you write that your main thread ends. Taken from the [pthread_create man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

The new thread terminates in one of the following ways:
[...]
       * Any of the threads in the process calls exit(3), or the main thread
         performs a return from main().  This causes the termination of all
         threads in the process.

Your main thread needs to `pthread_join` to wait for the sender to terminate.